# Plot multiple lines between and x and a y column based on a third column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

First question on Stack Overflow! New to Pandas. I have data, a snippet of which is pasted below. I want to plot Hits (Y-axis) against Week (X-axis), with multiple line graphs, one for each experiment group.

I'm confused as to what exactly to do. I know I likely need to use groupby. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[Hits, Experiment Group, Week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5k0z.png)

Comment: You should post your code and your desirable output, inserting a picture will not help

Comment: It's easier for us to help you solve a specific issue. Can you add any code you've written to solve the problem? Then we can see where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Solution found. The issue was, I didn't know that we needed to unstack. A good link for those looking to plot lines by groups of their data:

https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/07/15/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-plot.html

Comment: Has the problem been solved?

Comment: Yes, solution similar to below:



hits_data['week']= pd.to_datetime(hits_data['week'])
# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# use unstack()
hits_data.groupby(['week','Experiment Group']).sum()['hits'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)

Comment: `df.pivot(index='week',columns='Experiment', values='Hits').plot.line()`You could also use a pivot.